# Is it possible to convert legacy ASP.NET projects targeting .NET Framework (4.8) to the SDK-style format and run them?

Tags: asp.net, .net, migration

I converted my ASP.NET MVC project targeting the .NET Framework (4.8) using the Visual Studio's Upgrade Assistant tool. However, I am unable to run the web application using Visual Studio. Following is the sample of the converted csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  ...
</Project>
```

When I try to launch the application using (Ctrl+F5) in the Visual Studio I get following error.

[image]

Is it possible to RUN the ASP.NET application targeting the .NET Framework (4.8) after converting to the SDK format?

Comment: Why did you tag this question as ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web is an MSBuild project SDK for building ASP.NET Core apps not ASP.NET  apps.and the output type should be console instead of class library for asp.net core apps

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Ok got it. Do you know what the equivalent for ASP.NET apps that target .NET Framework is?